# Can Neutrinos be used in space telescope?

Tags: neutrinos, estimation, telescopes, space-mission

Can we use neutrinos in the modern electronic devices such as Telescopes for capturing images, which are far from current human reach?

Comment: There are neutrino 'telescopes' in operation, but they do not capture images per se, only detect neutrinos and the direction they come from.

Comment: FWIW, electronic devices use (surprise!) _electrons_.  A device that did any kind of signalling, image processing, computing, etc. using neutrinos would have a different name. "Neutrinonic?"

Comment: @jameslarge I'm not sure what you mean by that, considering the fact that telescopes (electronic or otherwise) are based on the detection of photons, but are not called "photonic."

Comment: Yeah, that's fair.  It's just, when AKJ said, "Telescope", I immediately thought of _optical_ telescopes, and its hard for me to think of an optical telescope as an "electronic device" no matter what you put at the prime focus or, how much computing power you use to turn the raw data into pretty pictures.

Comment: More than slightly relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135162/what-exactly-do-we-see-on-the-famous-neutrino-image-of-the-sun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably not, because neutrinos are very hard to detect: most of them would go straight through the imaging device without registering their presence- thus, to catch enough to make an image, the detector would need to be gigantic: perhaps  thousands of meters on a side or more. In addition, because of that property (they interact almost not at all with matter) it would be impossible to construct a lens array which would bring a neutrino "image" into focus on the imaging device.

Comment: Although if you measure the direction of a neutrino from a cerenkov detector you can produce an image. We don't focus radio waves in an interferometer but we can make radio 'images'

Comment: not probably, surely, considering the interaction crossections, no telescope with focus etc can be constructed.